# Getting average system CPU usage over a time interval in Java (linux)

Tags: java, linux, cpu-usage

I basically want the result of `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad()` averaged over a time interval, say 60 seconds.

`java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` has `getSystemLoadAverage()`, however from what I've read, that gets the 'CPU load' instead of 'CPU usage', which is calculated differently.

Is there a pre-existing API of some sorts to get what I want, or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score -1):

If you want an average to be meaningful in any way, it needs to be an average of some data-set that's greater than 1.

Query the system for the current CPU-load, in a regular interval, like once every second, and save the results of each query over time in a collection of some sort, like an array.

After that, you can get the average of the latest 60 entries in the array, and that will be your average CPU-load for the last 60 seconds (with a 1-second precision).

If you don't know how to average something, that would be `average = sum_of_elements_values / number_of_elements`.

If you want some form of "absolute" precision, instead of a 1-second precision, all that changes is that you'll have to query every CPU-cycle.